# How to share wordpress session data to codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I have website in wordpress and also have website in codeigniter on same hosting .I want to access wordpress user data to codeigniter .

For ex: when user login in wordpress website then automatically fetch the user information on codeigniter websiste .

[www.demo.com](http://www.demo.com) wordpress website

[www.demo.com/crm](http://www.demo.com/crm) in codeigniter 3 .

Thank you

want to get session data in codeigniter

Comment: see i have website on primary domain which is bulit with wordpress .
when someone login in wordpress website then i want to access wordpress user information to codeigniter application using session or cookie i don't have any idea how to do

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What do you mean by "primary domain"? The current question doesn't use distinct domains

Comment: my wordpress website host on this url for ex: www.demo.com and i have second application crm which hosted on same domain within sub folder ex:  www.demo.com/crm
Now when user login on this domain www.demo.com after login user will show the crm link on this www.demo.com  when some one click on that link then all information about the user name user email user id want to access on my www.demo.com/crm folder .
 crm built in codeigniter 3

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it**